# Ember - get target url of transition

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, ember.js

I am creating an error hook in my Ember.js app to redirect you to the auth service if you are not allowed to view certain content (in other words, if the server returns a 401).

It looks like this:

```
Ember.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  error: function(error, transition){
    if (error.status === 401) {
      window.location.replace("https://auth.censored.co.za");
    }
  }
```

Our auth api works as follows: If you send it a parameter called `target` (which is a url), it will redirect you back to that target url after you've logged in.

So I want to somehow get the URL of the route the Ember app was trying to transition to.

Then my code will end up something like this

```
Ember.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  error: function(error, transition){
    if (error.status === 401) {
      var target = // Your answer here
      window.location.replace("https://auth.censored.co.za?target=" + encodeURIComponent(target));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across a need for this too, and resorted to using some internal APIs. In my case, I wanted to reload the whole app so that if you're switching users there's not data left over from the other user. When I reload the app, I want to put the user at the URL they tried to transition to, but for which they had insufficient privileges. After they authenticate (and thus have the bearer token in localstorage) I wanted to use `window.location.replace(url)` to get a clean copy of the whole app with the user at the URL implied by the Ember `Transition` object. But the question was, how do I go from a `Transition` object to a URL? Here is my solution, which uses the `generate` method which is a private API of the router:

```
  let paramsCount = 0;
  let params = {};
  let args = [transition.targetName];
  // Iterate over route segments
  for (let key1 in transition.params) {
    if (transition.params.hasOwnProperty(key1)) {
      let segment = transition.params[key1];
      // Iterate over the params for the route segment.
      for (let key2 in segment) {
        if (segment.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
          if (segment[key2] != null) {
            params[key2] = segment[key2];
            paramsCount++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (paramsCount > 0) {
    args.push(params);
  }
  let url = router.generate.apply(router, args);
```

You'll need to get the router somehow either with a container lookup or some other means. I got it by injecting the `-routing` service which is documented as an API that might be publically exposed in the future (used by `link-to`), and which happens to have the router as a property.

While messy, perhaps you might find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use `transition.intent.url` to accomplish exactly this. I'm not sure if this is private or not -- relevant discussion: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/getting-url-from-ember-router-transition-for-sso-login/7079/2.

Answer (score 1):

After spending several hours searching for an answer to this question and using the Chrome debugger to try and reverse engineer the Ember 2.5 code, my conclusion is that what you are looking for is not possible at the present time.

For people who don't understand why someone wants to do this, the case arises when authentication (e.g the login page) is separated from the application. This is necessary if there is a requirement not to deliver any content (including the application itself) to the user if the user is not authenticated. In other words, the login page cannot be part of the application because the user is not allowed to access the application before logging in.

PS: I realize this is not a solution to the user's question and probably more suitable as a comment. However, I can't post comments.

Comment: "There is no solution" is also a valid answer - Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Kevins answer is the most correct one, I came to a similar solution. Basically I found how the `link-to` component was populating the `href` attribute and used the same sort of code.

In your object inject `-routing`. I did so with:

```
'routing': Ember.inject.service('-routing'),
```

Then the code to generate the URL from the transition is as follows...

```
let routing = this.get('routing');
let params = Object.values(transition.params).filter(param => {
  return Object.values(param).length;
});
let url = routing.generateURL(transition.targetName, params, transition.queryParams);
```